# Spring boot: Unable to resolve static content

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to resolve static content path with spring-boot? App is unable to locate following css. Need I implement addResourceHandlers method? Or spring-boot provides easy configuration?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/sghome.css" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need to use relative path. Use following instead :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sghome.css" />
```

Comment: Indeed, Spring maps both static/ (or public/) and templates/ to the root. The main difference between the two is that the templates/ is for dynamic templates (thymeleaf, velocity, ...) and the other one is for static resources (CSS, JS, images, ...), but you can use them as if they were in the same folder.

Comment: @g00glen00b Thanks for explanation.